# How to implement the favorite functionality in the android gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'm having an app, where i'm display some information in the gridview. Now i need to add favorite functionality to the same gridview. Please help me with this. I tried googling, but no luck.

Comment: implement custom adapter for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom checkbox for favorite in gridview items

here is code for checkbox

```
  <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:button="@drawable/customdrawablecheckbox" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

here is code for custom drawable

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_favorite" />
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_favoritecheck" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_favorite" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. can you please provide me a custom gridview adapter.

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html      http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

Comment: Thank you Ram.Currently i'm using frame layout. How to make this checkbox to align left or right or top-left etc.   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" is a invalid parameter in framelayout

Comment: why you are not using relative layout instead of framelayout?

Comment: Ok Ram. i will be using that. How to make checkbox to top right corner?

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_profile"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_user" 
       />